# Testflight - How to let users sign themselves up for beta

Tags: web-services, app-store-connect, testflight

Apple introduced Testflight as a way for developers to beta test apps quickly and efficiently. While the intention is well, signing up users for the open beta is not completely automatic. Currently, the developer has to:

1. obtain tester's email,
2. add email to a list of beta testers on iTunesConnect, and
3. send out an invitation email.

This is obviously very cumbersome because it *requires* the developer to do these things by hand. Even if we keep a Google Doc and add all the emails every day, the delay between a user putting the email on the doc and getting that invitation may cause the tester to become disinterested.

The question is, has anyone figured out a way to automate the process? Ideally, as soon as the user inputs an email on a web form, or by some other means, a script will add that to the list and send out an invitation on the fly. Is there some kind of set up to handle this without manual labour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is a development question but you can have a look at https://github.com/fastlane/boarding

Best,

Nicolas

Comment: This sounds very promising. Will be trying this out!